# Polygon (ex-Matic): L1 and L2 communication

Tags: layer-2, polygon

I try to send a URI to the layer 2 (Matic sidechain) from the "ERC721 Dummy contract" as Matic/Polygon team calls it and deployed on L1 (Ethereum mainnet). Their current Dummy ERC721 template only works with a baseURI + token ID format, not a full on-chain URI storage as I use with OpenZeppelin URIStorage contract (best way for my dapp to scale) deployed on the Matic Mumbai test net ([Contract link](https://polygon-explorer-mumbai.chainstacklabs.com/address/0x00ECd527BC1e0d93C7EEb6d6F6C3767bcf988961/contracts)). The trick here is that they use a proxy contract called a ChainManager to manage this L1 to L2 communication, and there is no official documentation on how sending custom messages between those two layers.
I could not find an answer from Matic team on their Discord nor official forum so I am trying here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [State Transfer](https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/l1-l2-communication/state-transfer/) which is the implementation of the [FX portal (flexible portal)](https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/l1-l2-communication/fx-portal). It allows passing arbitrary data between Matic and Ethereum.

Fx portal leverages state sync and checkpoint mechanism of polygon architecture.

Fx-portal Github: https://github.com/fx-portal/contracts

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot ! So I understand that I can design my own L1/L2 bridge for my ERC721 tokens (or any other standard). I will investigate it, I hope this is not too complex, the PoS Bridge was quite handy but not flexible enough and that makes sense.